# on live agent pre Chat window why can't I add Description from the Case

Tags: liveagent, embedded-services

On Live Agent Pre-Chat in Chat Setting page I am not able to add Description from the Case. I can add other field from the Case why isn't in the selection?

Answer (score 0):

The out-of-the-box pre chat form has certain limitations and doesn't support all fields and features.
The workaround for this is to use a custom aura / web components.
We had to take this approach as the standard pre-chat form doesn't support picklist dependencies and we needed to have a dependent picklist on our form for case categorization.

Here's some documentation around it : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_lightning_components.htm

Hope this is helpful.

Best,
Vishal